# Update one column of table from join from another two tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, dblink

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_POLICY SET POLICYHOLDER_NAME=(select A.first_name||' '||A.last_name "Name",B.POLICY_NO from 
NIC_GS.T_NIC_POLICY_CUST_INFO@DBLINK_EBAO A JOIN NIC_GS.T_POLICY_general@DBLINK_EBAO B ON A.POLICY_ID=B.POLICY_ID where 
B.POLICY_NO IN(SELECT POLICY_NUMBER FROM CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_POLICY)) 
where  POLICY_NUMBER in(SELECT POLICY_NUMBER FROM CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_POLICY);
```

SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"  is showing.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00913: too many values` --> You want to update only single column but passing 2 values using sub-query (2 columns in sub-query)

Just remove `B.POLICY_NO` from `SELECT` clause of the sub query as follows:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_POLICY O
   SET POLICYHOLDER_NAME=(select MAX(A.first_name||' '||A.last_name) "Name" 
                            from NIC_GS.T_NIC_POLICY_CUST_INFO@DBLINK_EBAO A 
                            JOIN NIC_GS.T_POLICY_general@DBLINK_EBAO B 
                              ON A.POLICY_ID=B.POLICY_ID 
                           where B.POLICY_NO = O.POLICY_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Even after removing I am getting error "SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"".

Comment: Is there any other way to update table without using sub query.

Comment: You are getting this error because you have not co-related your table with a subquery. Your sub-query is returning multiple records where a single record(row) is expected. I have updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.